# Sharing String between threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to request multiple URLs with multiple `std::thread`. This is how my code looks so far:

```
fn fetch(urls: Vec<&str>) {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for url in urls {
        let tx = tx.clone();

        thread::spawn(|| {
            let ssl = NativeTlsClient::new().unwrap();
            let connector = HttpsConnector::new(ssl);
            let client = Client::with_connector(connector);
            let mut res = client.get(url).send().unwrap();
            let mut result = String::new();
            res.read_to_string(&mut result);

            tx.send(result).unwrap();  
        });
    }

    //let mut result: Vec<String> = vec![];
    for _ in urls {
        println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    }
}
```

But I got an error that said:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied
    --> src/lib.rs:18:9
    |
 18 |         thread::spawn(|| {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>`
    |
    = note: `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:18:23: 29:10 url:&&str, tx:&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>]`
    = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

When I tried to put the `move` in the `thread::spawn`:

```
thread::spawn(move || {
    ...
```

I got another error related to lifetime:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:15:16
   |
15 |     for url in urls {
   |                ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 12:26...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:27
   |
12 | fn fetch(urls: Vec<&str>) {
   |                           ^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::vec::Vec<&str>, found std::vec::Vec<&str>)
  --> src/lib.rs:15:16
   |
15 |     for url in urls {
   |                ^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:18:23: 27:10 url:&str, tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::string::String>]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, what is the proper way to send strings from threads through channel here? And how can I solve the lifetime problem in the later error?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding the `move` is the correct solution to your first problem. The second error indicates a problem in your code that was there before already, but is detected only in a later compiler stage. So what does this second error mean?

Well, a spawned thread *can* run forever (more precisely: as long as the main thread/the whole program runs). In your case they don't, because you block the calling thread waiting for the results from the channel. But the compiler doesn't know that. Therefore, `thread::spawn()` requires the passed closure to be `: 'static` which means that it doesn't reference anything that lives shorter than the whole program.

But in your case the closure has a reference to the url, a `&str`. But how long does the string behind that reference actually live? Not necessarily forever! That's the problem here.

The best solution is likely to use [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html). This API makes sure that the spawned thread doesn't outlive its parent, so you can just reference the `&str` inside of your closure.

Other typical solutions to this, but which likely won't work well for you:

- Use an `Arc` and wrap the owned value in it. But this is not possible here, because your function does not have access to the owned value.
- Change your function signature to `fn fetch(urls: Vec<&'static str>)`. It works, but it limits the callers of your function as they have to provide static strings. I guess that the list of URLs is not just a list of string literals, but dynamically generated; so this is not really a solution for you.
- Clone the `&str` to move the resulting `String` into the closure. This is not really a nice solution, though, as useless clones should be avoided. But it could be tolerable in your situation as the HTTP request will takes a whole lot longer than cloning a rather small (url) string.

Comment: Beautiful answer.  Helping me with my understanding of rust for an almost identical issue.