# Why do we need std::thread::scope if we can just use thread.join() to drop references within the lifetime of the function?

Tags: rust

I am confused about how lifetimes on references to objects are managed when using concurrency with `std::thread`.

I think I understand the core problem that I/Rust wants to solve, which is that If I pass a function a reference to an object, and that function spawns threads which use that reference, I need to make sure that the original bit of data is going to last at least as long as the threads that I spawned. I read Lukas Kalbertodt's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467829/sharing-string-between-threads-in-rust) and I understand that I can do this with `std::thread::scope`. I have attached a simple example, below:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let owned_string: String = String::from("OWNED DATA");
    foo(&owned_string);
}

fn foo(data: &str) {
    thread::scope( |s| {
        s.spawn(move || {
            println!("I am doing something in the first thread!");
            println!("I have the data, look: {}", &data);
        });

        s.spawn(move || {
            println!("I am doing something in the second thread!");
            println!("I have the data, too, look: {}", &data);
        });
    });
}
```

This prints something like

```
I am doing something in the first thread!
I have the data, look: OWNED DATA
I am doing something in the second thread!
I have the data, too, look: OWNED DATA
```

To clarify, this all works because the use of `thread::scope` means that the use of the references in the threads are wholly contained within the defined scope. The references are dropped (I think) when that scope ends, which is before when the function returns. The data itself can't be dropped before the function returns, so overall the program is memory safe because there is no way for the references to dangle.

By contrast, if there were no `thread::scope`, but the threads were simply spawned, then the function could somehow return before the threads ended, and as such the referenced data could potentially go out of scope, leading to the references dangling.

What I don't understand is why I can't achieve the same functionality with `handle.join()` within the function. For example:

```
fn bar(data: &str) {
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("I am doing something in the first thread!");
        println!("I have the data, look: {}", &data);
    }));

    handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("I am doing something in the second thread!");
        println!("I have the data, too, look: {}", &data);
    }));

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join();
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, and the compiler tells me that:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/main.rs:24:18
   |
22 |   fn bar(data: &str) {
   |          ----  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |          |
   |          `data` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
23 |       let mut handles = Vec::new();
24 |       handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   |  __________________^
25 | |         println!("I am doing something in the first thread!");
26 | |         println!("I have the data, look: {}", &data);
27 | |     }));
   | |      ^
   | |      |
   | |______`data` escapes the function body here
   |        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
```

In principle, I understand what it is saying (I think), but I also understand that when I call the loop to do `handle.join()` over the handles, this blocks until all the threads have finished. Therefore, there is no way for the function to return before all the threads have completed and the reference can safely drop.

Can someone please explain why the second example is not memory safe? Or, is this an example of the Rust compiler being overly conservative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the case with such general/broad design decisions, there is no obvious answer: Yes, it could have been designed in other ways, to benefit such and such use case; but that would have been detriment to such and such use case on such and such systems...

Here are a couple of things one needs to consider:

- The underlying OS is under no obligation to actually execute any of those threads (unless it would result in a deadlock), even after returning from `spawn()`. That includes not executing the "sub-threads" until the main thread has already exited.
- There is nothing that forces you to call `.join()` at all, and the compiler can't proof for the general case that `if random() == 42 { my_thread.join() }`  will execute.
- The spawning thread might `panic!()` before `join()` is called, so it's never called at all. But the "sub-threads" will execute (see first point)
- What if you `joined()` some threads, but others only if `is_np_equal_to_p()` is `False`? The compiler can't statically proof that every execution path is sound unless it can proof the result of `is_np_equal_to_p()`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `thread::spawn` and non-`'static` references is that nothing forces you to `join` the threads, so you can't rely on `join` for soundness, but non `'static` references might become dangling before you actually call `join` so a safe  `spawn` can only take `FnOnce + 'static`.

On the other hand `thread::scope` does force all the outstanding threads to join in the `impl Drop` of the returned value so there are no issues.

Comment: And to expand on it, it's the [leakpocalypse](https://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/everyone-poops/), this was a *huge* problem when people realised it and led to a fair bit of issues, reworking, and emergency removal as this happened fairly close to when 1.0 was going to be cut, took 7 years for scoped threads to make it back in, and scoped (async) tasks still are not a thing.