Cannot await for a function in an async function of Tauri::command
I cant await for a function if i use a Tauri function.
I am really new to RUST and dont know much about futures and stuff, My program worked well in the terminal but now i just want to make a good UI so i am using tauri, it does not allow me to call an async function
GitHub link
This is the github link :) https://github.com/HashirShazad/ChughtaiDownloader This might help in reproducing the error.
Main.rs
#[tauri::command(rename_all = "snake_case")]
async fn url_entered(url: &str, img_box_checked:bool, pdf_box_checked:bool, subfolder_box_checked:bool) -> Result<String, ()> {
    println!("IMAGE:{} | PDF:{} | Folder:{} | URL: {}", img_box_checked, pdf_box_checked, subfolder_box_checked, url);


    let _ = get_table(url, CURRENT_DIRECTORY, pdf_box_checked, img_box_checked, subfolder_box_checked).await; // Await here causes error

    Ok(format!("Sending request to: {}", url))
}

Main.js
const { invoke } = window.__TAURI__.tauri;

let urlInputEl;
let urlMsgEl;
let downloadPdfs;
let downloadImages;
let scanSubfolders;
async function url_submitted() {
  urlMsgEl.textContent = "Trying to download...";
  // Learn more about Tauri commands at https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command
  const { url, img_box_checked, pdf_box_checked, subfolder_box_checked } = {
    url: urlInputEl.value,
    img_box_checked: downloadImages.checked,
    pdf_box_checked: downloadPdfs.checked,
    subfolder_box_checked: scanSubfolders.checked
  };

  urlMsgEl.textContent = await invoke("url_entered", { url, img_box_checked, pdf_box_checked, subfolder_box_checked }).then(() =>
    console.log('Completed!'));
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  urlInputEl = document.querySelector("#url-input");
  urlMsgEl = document.querySelector("#url-msg");
  downloadPdfs = document.querySelector("#DownloadPdfs");
  downloadImages = document.querySelector("#DownloadImages");
  scanSubfolders = document.querySelector("#ScanSubfolders");

  document.querySelector("#url-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    url_submitted();
  });
});

There is a button in html:
<button type="submit">Enter</button>

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:214:1
    |
214 | #[tauri::command(rename_all = "snake_case")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `url_entered` is not `Send`
...
231 |         .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![url_entered])
    |                         ------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
    |
    = help: within `ego_tree::Node<scraper::Node>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::Cell<NonZero<usize>>`, which is required by `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>: std::marker::Send`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\main.rs:89:90
    |
35  |     for table in html.select(&table_selector){ // get all tables from html
    |         ----- has type `ElementRef<'_>` which is not `Send`
...
89  |                                          download_pdfs, download_imgs, scan_subfolders)).await?; // Call get_table function with new url
    |                                                                                          ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `table` maybe used later
note: required by a bound in `ResultFutureTag::future`
   --> C:\Users\DELL\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tauri-1.6.8\src\command.rs:293:42
    |
289 |     pub fn future<T, E, F>(self, value: F) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Value, InvokeError>>
    |            ------ required by a bound in this associated function
...
293 |       F: Future<Output = Result<T, E>> + Send,
    |                                          ^^^^ required by this bound in `ResultFutureTag::future`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `__cmd__url_entered` which comes from the expansion of the macro `tauri::generate_handler` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)


I tried searching on google and use codeium but nothing worked.

Please add a [mre].

The error of future cannot be sent between threads safely generally says that your types do not implement Send traits. Please try moving a clone of url: &str, into the fn instead of passing a &str. (e.g. url: String)

@Raeisi both &str and String are send so that can't be the problem.

Nope @cafce25. You cannot normally share any references between threads. Static lifetime and Arc are required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467829/sharing-string-between-threads-in-rust. Overall, the error is caused by the Send issue.

&str is not generally 'static, yes, but that's totally unrelated to Send. The error OP has complains about missing Send, not about a unfulfilled 'static bound so it can't be related to &str vs String. Also you absolutely can use regular references with threads: How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?
